# c# multiple instances of methods?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a c# program.
the form1 of the program makes new instances of form3 on different thread from time to time.
so each of the form3 instances contains these methods.
I suspect that the problem occours when two threads calls the same method at the same time or while another thread is allready using one of them. especially because they have the same webbrowser name

```
private void vent()
{
     while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
     {
         Application.DoEvents();
     }
}

public bool containss(string SearchText)
{
     string page = wb.Document.Body.InnerText;
     if (page.ToLower().Contains(SearchText.ToLower())) 
         return true;
     else return false;
}
```

The Problem with this containss() method is that it works with

```
string page = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
```

and not

```
string page = wb.Document.Body.InnerText;
```

I get: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
on this line:

```
if (page.ToLower().Contains(SearchText.ToLower()))
```

I make the threads like this:

```
private void ThreadProc()
        {
            Form frm = new Form3(currentAB);
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }

Thread ab1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
ab1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
ab1.Start();
```

Comment: How/where are you initializing `string SearchText`?

Comment: I just call the method like this: containss("sometext");

Comment: How is `wb` defined? is it static?

Comment: private void wb1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           
        }